# How to specify a loss function to penalize the wrong order of outputs

Tags: residuals, regularization, loss-functions

I am looking for an existing loss function (or regularizer) to penalize a loss that is based on the wrong order of outputs. Let me visualize this using the residual sum of squares (with a $j$-dimensional output $O$):

$
\begin{align}
\text{RSS} = \sum_{i=i}^{N} \sum_{j=1}^{O} \left(\hat{y}_i^{(j)} - y_i^{(j)}\right)^2
\end{align}
$,

where $\hat{y}_i$ is the prediction for datum $i,$ and $y_i$ the corresponding ground truth. Now assume a problem where I am interested in two outcomes at the same time, say, $o_1,o_2$. These should be binary so that I want the underlying model to learn to predict either $0$ or $1$ for each. All possible (and optimal) outcomes are thus $\big[ \{0,0\}, \{0,1\}, \{1,0\}, \{1,1\} \big]$.

However, the first of these outcomes, $o_1$, is **more important** in a sense that the loss should penalize a prediction of $\{1,0\}$ **more** than $\{0,1\}$, if the true output were $\{0,0\}$. In general, any $o_j$ is more important than $o_{j+1}$. If I were to use $\text{RSS}$, the penalty would be the same for either outcome.

I have been thinking about introducing an additional weight for each output and to include it in the RSS, such as

$
\begin{align}
\text{RSS} = \sum_{i=1}^{N} \sum_{j=i}^{O} \left(w_j\!\left(\hat{y}_i^{(j)} - y_i^{(j)}\right)\right)^2,
\\
\\
\text{and} \; \forall\,w_j > 1 \; \land \; w_j > w_{j+1}.
\end{align}
$

However, I would rather not roll my own solution. So I was curious, whether something like this exists?

Comment: Your solution seems sensible. You could also have powers different from 2 that decrease with $k$. The possibilities are infinite. The loss function is ultimately determined by the specific nature of your problem, and could be determined by monetary considerations for example (in fact it includes the contribution of a utility function from Decision Theory). Finding a loss function that well represents the gain/losses involved in the problem is often extremely difficult. There are no general, fit-all solutions.